# React Native: Module not found: Can't resolve './src/BlurView'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I m trying to import **Blur View** in my app but I m getting this error:-

**Module not found: Can't resolve './src/BlurView'**

---

**MY CODE**

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import { BlurView } from "@react-native-community/blur";


const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={require ('./assets/bg.jpg') } style={styles.image}>
      <View style= {styles.main_container}>
      
      <View style= {styles.button_container}>
      <Button title= '1' color= '#ffffff00' />
      
      </View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: undefined,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff30',
  },
  
  button_container: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
    borderTopRightRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff70',
    height: '70%',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    
  },
  
  button: {
    color: '#ffffff00',
  },
  
  
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "stretch",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: '100%',
    width: undefined,
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000000a0"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Im just getting This error by importing Blur View.

Please tell me whats the problem here.

**Versions--**

React-Native -- 0.63.2

---

BTW Im getting TypeError in linear gradient package too..

Comment: Have you solved the problem already?

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly compile your app after the package installation?

As it requires a pod installation and a specific setup for Android, it won't work properly before a react-native run

additional instructions at https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur